# How can I make a more permanent connection to cheap sensors?

Tags: circuit-design, sensor, connector

I am working on a project that uses sensors like the one in this image. I thought I could just drop them directly into some terminal connectors but they don't fit (too short) and also I'm thinking it would be nice to have it wired in anyways. Do I have to solder it on/off every time (they are really small and I'm not very skilled,) or is there a solution to this I am unaware of? These sensors are force sensing resistors (FSR) used in a hobby project.

I am just looking for a quick and convenient way to connect and switch out sensors to a more permanent circuit board.

[image]

Comment: What is the exact pitch? (Center-to-center distance between the two pins.)

Answer (score 8):

Looks like they're 2.54mm pitch and flat, so you could use a SIP or DIP socket such as an 8-pin socket like you'd use for an 8-pin DIP IC. Not the machined type, which probably won't fit well, the more inexpensive dual wipe type like this (image from Digikey for the part number shown):

[image]

Datasheet [here](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/10/382438.pdf).

Longer term, consider making a small transition PCB.

Answer (score 6):

If the supplied leads are too short, you could solder extra wire to them, heat shrink the splices, and then use the longer lead length to connect to any type of connector you like.

Answer (score 2):

My brief googling of the subject suggests you want to look into Clincher(tm) flex connectors from Amphenol.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful in responding to have the actual part number of the subject sensor. The details of the device are important, like the conductor size, spacing, heat sensitivity, etc. Viable options could consist of an IC socket, as mentioned by Spehro Pefhany. There is low temperature, environmental solder splice for adding pigtails. There is the option to wire-wrap the leads directly to the PCB. Crimp splicing pigtails may also be an option, depending on the leads supplied. It's also possible the OEM has a specific option available, or in mind.